How to Set Up an A/B Test for Bidding Strategies with Uncontrolled Spend but Measured ROI?
I'm conducting an A/B test comparing two bidding strategies for online auctions. One strategy (the fixed strategy) simply bids a fixed ammount of money (on average) per auction. The other strategy adapts the ammount bid based on performance over the last few auctions.
The challenge is that I cannot directly control the amount of money each strategy spends. The target cost per activation (CPA) determines the total spend, which in turn affects the number of conversions and ultimately, the return on investment (ROI). The only aspect I can control is the duration of the experiment.
My goal is to determine whether the adaptive strategy can outperform the fixed strategy by at least 10% in terms of ROI.
Here are a few key questions I have:

What is the appropriate randomisation unit in this case? We can't be certain that the dollar ammounts or the number of conversions are at all comparible between experiment variations.

Given the uncertainty over the randomisation unit, is the simple total profit (revenue - spend) an appropriate metric to determine the outcome of the experiment? What is an appropriate method for statistical inference in this case (I have read this post as a starter).

Sample size & duration: How do I determine the appropriate sample size or experiment duration to detect a 10% uplift in ROI with statistical significance? Is it even correct to think of randomisation units being days?

Variance estimation: Given that spend is not directly controlled but influenced by target CPA, what metrics or techniques should I use to accurately estimate the variance in ROI across both groups?

Bias mitigation: How can I account for differences in spend or conversion patterns that might create bias, especially if one strategy adapts faster than the other?

Stopping rules: Since I can only control how long the experiment runs, what would be appropriate stopping criteria or statistical tests to apply during and after the experiment to ensure the results are reliable?


Any guidance on the best practices for setting up this type of test, including potential pitfalls or methods to ensure robust results, would be greatly appreciated!


What is the appropriate randomization unit in this case? We can't be certain that the dollar amounts or the number of conversions are at all comparable between experiment variations.

I recommend using the individual auction as the randomization unit. By randomly assigning each auction to either the fixed or adaptive bidding strategy, you ensure that both strategies are tested under similar conditions. This approach maintains independence between units and allows for a fair comparison of the strategies.

Given the uncertainty over the randomization unit, is the simple total profit (revenue - spend) an appropriate metric to determine the outcome of the experiment? What is an appropriate method for statistical inference in this case?

Considering your goal is to detect a 10% uplift in ROI, using ROI [(Revenue - Spend) / Spend] as your primary metric makes sense. For statistical inference, bootstrapping is a practical method. It allows you to estimate confidence intervals and perform hypothesis testing on ROI without relying on strict parametric assumptions about the data's distribution.

Sample size & duration: How do I determine the appropriate sample size or experiment duration to detect a 10% uplift in ROI with statistical significance? Is it even correct to think of randomization units being days?

You'll need to conduct a power analysis to determine the required sample size. This involves estimating the baseline ROI, its standard deviation, the desired effect size (10% uplift), and the level of statistical power you want (usually 80%). This calculation will give you the number of auctions needed. While you could consider days as units, it's more effective to randomize at the auction level to enhance statistical power and maintain independence between observations.

Variance estimation: Given that spend is not directly controlled but influenced by target CPA, what metrics or techniques should I use to accurately estimate the variance in ROI across both groups?

Bootstrapping is a suitable technique here. By resampling your data with replacement, you can create an empirical distribution of the ROI differences between the two strategies. This method doesn't depend on parametric assumptions and provides a way to estimate variance and confidence intervals directly from your data. Alternatively, if you can express ROI as a function of underlying random variables (like revenue and spend), the delta method can offer an approximate variance estimation.

Bias mitigation: How can I account for differences in spend or conversion patterns that might create bias, especially if one strategy adapts faster than the other?

To mitigate bias: Balance the total spend between the two strategies by adjusting target CPAs or pacing controls to ensure they're comparable. Implement stratified randomization by grouping auctions based on key characteristics (e.g., time of day, user demographics) and randomizing within these groups to ensure both strategies are exposed to similar conditions. Adjust for covariates in your analysis. Using regression models that include relevant covariates can help account for residual differences between the groups.

Stopping rules: Since I can only control how long the experiment runs, what would be appropriate stopping criteria or statistical tests to apply during and after the experiment to ensure the results are reliable?

It's best to predefine the experiment duration based on your sample size calculation to achieve the desired statistical power. Avoid stopping the experiment early based on interim results, as this can increase the risk of Type I errors (false positives). If interim analysis is necessary, consider using methods like group sequential designs with appropriate statistical adjustments to control for multiple looks at the data. After completing the experiment, perform your hypothesis tests using appropriate statistical methods (e.g., two-sample t-test or non-parametric tests if assumptions aren't met) and report confidence intervals for the ROI difference to assess the significance and reliability of your results.

The challenge with this approach is that we don't control the randomisation process, a third party does. So, we only have the option of continuing with an experiment or stopping it.

Ok, then just predefine a stopping date. The stopping rule should not depend on the results, just on the number of data points.
